# Прокси сервер

Tags: windows, прокси

На основе чего формируется прокси сервер? Например, есть сеть - у каждого свой ИП. И что? Почему прокси выглядит 10.25.25.2, а не, например, 10. 27.27.7 или 10.255.255.0?

И еще. Например у компа полетела винда, как узнать, какой ИП был у этого компа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вопрос не до конца понятен, как и второй. Поэтому, возможно, вам поможет [данная статья](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Прокси-сервер).

Адрес прокси сервера может выглядеть как угодно. Естественно, для внутренних нужд необходимо выбирать [частные IP-адреса и диапазоны](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%E0%F1%F2%ED%FB%E9_IP-%E0%E4%F0%E5%F1)

Без записей (логов) о том, какой был IP и без DHCP сервера в сети, вы вряд ли узнаете, какой был IP у компьютера с "полетевшей" виндой.